# How to ensure an Express app closes and releases the port when your process dies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemon

I'm using [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) to run my Express server in development and auto-restart my process whenever a file changes. When it restarts, it frequently errors with "Port 3000 is already in use".

Killing nodemon, running `killall node`, and then restarting nodemon fixes it temporarily. But I want to fix it properly, and make sure the port gets released every time the app gets killed.

I've tried using [signal-exit](https://github.com/tapjs/signal-exit) to manually call `server.close()` as a cleanup job:

```
const onExit = require('signal-exit')

onExit(() => {
  server.close();
});
```

But that doesn't work either. It still frequently fails to release the port. Any ideas?

Comment: you can try process.on("exit", ... or process.on("SIGINT", ...

Comment: @FluffyNights that's exactly what signal-exit does, just in a more robust way.

Comment: What OS are you using? Never had this problem in Ubuntu.

Comment: Mac OS X El Capitan